# Call function from dict with args

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to call a function from a dictionary..

```
def target(Enemy):
hero.target = Enemy

commands = {
                'close':close,
                'weapon attack':wpnatk,
                'spell attack':splatk,
                'flee':flee,
                'look':look,
                'target':target
    }
    inp = str(input('>>'))
    if inp in commands:
        commands[inp]()
```

How can I push the argument to the function? If I recall you don't add the parens in the dictionary.

Comment: You "push the argument" the same way you would for a "normal" function: put it in the parentheses.

Comment: It gets called from the if statement. Would an input split work with commands[inp](inp[-1]) so that the last part of the input becomes the argument?

Comment: Except that only works on something like 'target dragon' but flee or close wouldn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

Just add the parenthesis at the end:

```
def target(n):
    print(n)

functions = {
    'function':target
}

functions['function'](1)
```